# Substring to nth character

Tags: objective-c

I need to substring to the 2nd comma in an NSString.

Input:

```
NSString *input = @"title, price, Camry, $19798, active";
```

Desired Output:

```
NSString *output = @"title, price";
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I have the following but the problem is it needs to skip the last comma:

```
NSString *output = [input rangeOfString:@"," options:NSBackwardsSearch];
```

Comment: You could make nested calls to -[NSString rangeOfString:]:, and find the  index of the 2nd occurrence of the comma, and then sub-string the whole input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code should do what you need:

```
NSString *input = @"title, price, Camry, $19798, active";

NSArray *array = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

NSArray *subArray = [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];

NSString *output = [subArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];

NSLog(output);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
- (NSString *)substringOfString:(NSString *)base untilNthOccurrence:(NSInteger)n ofString:(NSString *)delim
{
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:base];
    NSInteger i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
         [scanner scanUpToString:delim intoString:NULL];
         [scanner scanString:delim intoString:NULL];
    }
    return [base substringToIndex:scanner.scanLocation - delim.length];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could **split -> splice -> join** that string like this in objc:

```
NSString *input = @"title, price, Camry, $19798, active";
// split by ", "
NSArray *elements = [input componentsSeparatedByString: @", "];
// grab the subarray
NSArray *subelements = [elements subarrayWithRange: NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
// concat by ", " again
NSString *output = [subelements componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
NSArray *items = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
NSString result = @"";
result = [result stringByAppendingString:[items objectAtIndex:0]];
result = [result stringByAppendingString:@", "];
result = [result stringByAppendingString:[items objectAtIndex:1]];
```

You have to check you have at least two items if you want avoid an exception.

Answer (score 0):

There's really nothing wrong with simply writing the code to do what you want.  Eg:

```
int commaCount = 0;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < input.count; i++) {
    if ([input characterAtIndex:i] == (unichar) ',') {
        commaCount++;
        if (commaCount == 2) break;
    }
}

NSString output = nil;
if (commaCount == 2) {
   output = [input substringToIndex:i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `NSString` category to handle finding nth occurrences of any string. This is example is for ARC.

```
//NSString+MyExtension.h

@interface NSString(MyExtension)
-(NSString*)substringToNthOccurrence:(NSUInteger)nth 
                            ofString:(NSString*)string;
-(NSString*)substringToNthOccurrence:(NSUInteger)nth 
                            ofString:(NSString*)string 
                             options:(NSStringCompareOptions)options;
@end
@implementation NSString(MyExtension)
-(NSString*)substringToNthOccurrence:(NSUInteger)nth 
                            ofString:(NSString*)string
{
    return [self substringToNthOccurrence:nth ofString:string options:0];
}
-(NSString*)substringToNthOccurrence:(NSUInteger)nth 
                            ofString:(NSString*)string 
                             options:(NSStringCompareOptions)options
{
    NSUInteger location = 0,
        strlength = [string length],
        mylength = [self length];

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(location, mylength);

    while(nth--)
    {
        location = [self rangeOfString:string 
                               options:options 
                                 range:range].location;   
        if(location == NSNotFound || (location + strlength) > mylength) 
        {
            return [self copy]; //nth occurrence not found
        }           
        if(nth == 0) strlength = 0; //This prevents the last occurence from being included

        range = NSMakeRange(location + strlength, mylength - strlength - location);
    }        
    return [self substringToIndex:location];
}
@end
```

---

```
//main.m
#import "NSString+MyExtension.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *output = [@"title, price, Camry, $19798, active" substringToNthOccurrence:2 ofString:@","];
        NSLog(@"%@", output);
    }
}
```

**I'll leave it as an exercise for someone to implement the mutable versions.*