# parsing string starting with @ and # in objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, regex, ipad

So I am trying to parse a string that has the following format:

## baz@marroon#red#blue #big@cat#dog

or, it can also be separated by spaces:

## baz @marroon #red #blue #big @cat #dog

and here's how I am doing it now:

```
- (void) parseTagsInComment:(NSString *) comment
{
    if ([comment length] > 0){
        NSArray * stringArray = [comment componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        for (NSString * word in stringArray){
            
        }
    }
}
```

I've got the components separated by space working, but what if it has no space.. how do I iterate through these words? I was thinking of using regex.. but I have no idea on how to write such regex in objective-C. Any idea, for a regex that would cover both of these cases?

Here's my first attempt:

```
NSError * error;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(@|#)\\S+" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    
    NSArray* wordArray = [regex matchesInString:comment 
                                      options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [comment length])];
    
    for (NSString * word in wordArray){
       
    }
```

Which doesn't work.. I think my regex is wrong.

Comment: Or try `[comment componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" #"]]`, which will break it up by both space and hash (but if you have both space and hash, it will break it up twice). Or obviously, if you wanted to do it just by the hash you could do `[comment componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"]`, but I assume there's some reason you didn't do it that way.

Comment: If you want to do regex, check out [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I did use NSRegularExpression.. my attempt is above

Comment: @RobertRyan the issue is that there may be # or @ in the string's

Comment: Try this (dupe?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708851/substring-to-nth-character/10709003#10709003

Comment: I apologize, but I'm not quite understanding what you're trying to parse (in your two examples above, are you looking for "baz","marroon","red","blue","big","cat","dog"?). Or something else? I'm not quite clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want the result to be an array of #baz, (atsign)marroon, #red, #blue, #big, @cat, #dog. I edited the sample input above too.. I hope it's clear

Comment: Your regex will be greedy, taking all non-whitespace it can so the first one will be "@marroon#red#blue" for the top one.  It also will never take the first one.  If you meant to have a hash on the first one, try this [#|@][A-Za-z]+

Comment: Hmm..I tried your regex.. but it didn't catch the @cat only the ones that started with #.. any ideas?

Comment: While @borrrden's string technically works for this example, it probably should be either `(#|@)[A-Za-z]+` or `[#@][A-Za-z]+`. And, regardless, it captures the @ words as well as the # words, so I don't know why it's not capturing @cat on your computer. Probably some silly syntactical issue.

Comment: Ah, I typed a random "or" symbol in there ><.  Silly of me.  Meant to type the second one you had.

Comment: @RobertRyan so I tried @"(#|@)\\S+" and it doesn't work when two tags are appended together

Comment: @adit Use "\\w" (which will stop at the next non-word character) instead of "\\S" (which goes to the next space), e.g. `@"(#|@)\\w+"`, as suggested in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10765333/1271826).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using NSScanner that puts the separated strings and a string representation of their ranges into an array (this assumes that your original string started with a # -- if it doesn't and you need it to, then just prepend the hash to the string at the start).

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSString *str = @"#baz@marroon#red#blue #big@cat#dog";
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
    NSCharacterSet *searchSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#@"];
    NSString *outputString;

    while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
        [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:searchSet intoString:nil];
        [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:searchSet intoString:&outputString];
        NSString *symbol = [outputString copy];
        [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:searchSet intoString:&outputString];
        NSString *wholePiece = [[symbol stringByAppendingString:outputString]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        NSString *rangeString = NSStringFromRange([str rangeOfString:wholePiece]);
        [array addObject:wholePiece];
        [array addObject:rangeString];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the regular expression you really want is `[@#]?\\w+`. It will find groups of letters optionally preceded by an @ or #. Your expression wouldn't work because it looks for any non-space character, which includes @ and #. (Depending on what can be in the "words," you might want something more or less specific than `\w`, but it isn't clear from the question.)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the ranges, then NSRegularExpression probably works well:

```
NSString *comment = @"@baz@marroon#red#blue #big@cat#dog";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[#@]\\w+" options:0 error:nil];

NSArray* wordArray = [regex matchesInString:comment 
                                    options:0 
                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [comment length])];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in wordArray)
    NSLog(@"%@", [comment substringWithRange:result.range]);
```

Or, `[@#][a-zA-z]+` works if you're ok with ASCII alpha words only.