# NSRegularExpression omitting certain character

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsregularexpression

So I had the following regex:

```
@"(#|@)\\S+"
```

however the \S here includes # and @ as well. How do I make this regex so that it's \S but not including # or @?

Basically I want a non white space character excluding # and @

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `(#|@)[^\s#@]+`. `[^\s#@]` will match everything except space characters, # and @.

And remember to double escape \ when put in the objective-c string literal.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo (an extra |). Try now.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude a set of characters u simply have to add ^ before it..so do it like ^(@|#)

you can use the following :-

```
NSStirng *string=@"Your String";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(@|#|\s)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

 NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0
range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];
```

Comment: so it's @"(#|@)^(@|#)\\S+" ??

Comment: based on the docs here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html ^ means matches the beginning of the line

Comment: no your above regex is not fine because you want to remove all of them  so u simply have to match it..see the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

As discussed on the [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763536/parsing-string-starting-with-and-in-objective-c) where you originally asked this question,

```
@"(#|@)\\w+"
```

will do what I think you want. If you *really* want every character except #, @, and whitespace, then

```
@"[#@][^@#\\s]+"
```

should do it. Both of these will take your string:

```
@"@baz@marroon#red#blue #big@cat#dog"
```

and if you use `matchesInString:options:range` it give you:

```
@"@baz"
@"@marroon"
@"#red"
@"#blue"
@"#big"
@"@cat"
@"#dog"
```

If this is not what you want, you should give us the input string and what you want as output, and we can tell you how to get it.